# SQL Server high logical reads vs scan count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

From a performance tuning perspective which one is more important?

Say a query reports 30 scans and 148 logical reads on a table with about 2 million records.

A modified version of the the same query reports 1 scan with 1400 logical reads.  Second query takes about 40ms less CPU time to execute.  Is the second query better?

I think so and this is my thesis:

In the first case, we have a high number of scans on a very large table.  This is costly on CPU and server memory, since all the rows in the table have to be loaded into memory. Executing such a query thousands of times will be taxing on server resources.

In the second case, we have less scans even though we are accumulating a higher number of logical reads.  Since logical reads effectively corresponds to number of pages being read from cache, the bottle neck here will be network bandwidth in getting the results back to the client.  The actual work SQL Server has to do in this case is less.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Stack overflow is a Q&A site and as such this question is not appropriate as it is likely to generate debate and opinion based answers.

Comment: Be sure to execute `DBCC  DOPCLEANBUFFERS` before running your queries in order to test queries with a cold buffer cache. Otherwise, you are going to have misleading results for physical count scans.

Comment: @GB, I do not think this is a debate.  There is certainly a recommended way to approach db optimization and this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The logical read metrics are mostly irrelevant. You care about time elapsed, CPU time spent and disk resources used. Why would you care about logical reads? They are accounted for by looking at CPU time.

If you want your query to go faster measure wall clock time. If you want to use less resources measure CPU and physical IO.

Comment: The only reason I am concerned about logical reads is because our service operations brought to our attention some queries generating logical reads in the billions and requesting for query optimization.  We think we have a more performance query. Execution plan is simpler and CPU time is less but on one table, logical reads is more.  So we need to convince ourselves that logical reads is irrelevant when it comes to performance before proposing solution as fix.

Comment: Then you need to find any problem at all with high logical reads. Be concrete. I don't know of any such problem. Logical reads are accounted for in the CPU time metric.